# Mapping two java object have same fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I want to map the fields of two java objects based on condition like below.

```
if(sourceObject.getField1() != null && targetObject.getField1() == null){
     targetObject.setFields1(sourceObject.getField1())
```

}

I am using mapstruct @MappingTarget annotation but it is not giving me what I am expecting like above.
I have multiple classes/subclasses with a hundred fields. Any suggestions or examples will help.

Comment: How does it look like now?

Comment: Still I had issue..Do you have any generic solution?

Comment: In order for me to give you an answer you'll need to share how the generated code looks like right now and how your mapper looks like

Comment: @VKR Please, can you review this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65367995/copy-changed-fields-into-an-object-in-java/65369332#65369332) I provided? It is very similar to your problem. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not a generic solution but if you have to do specific things, you can do it in a @AfterMapping annotated method.