# Compare objects and create a new one similar to one of them

Tags: java, reflection, compareobject

I want to compare 2 objects and create a new one with the values of the second if its values are not null. Otherwise the values of the first one should be copied to the object created.
My problem is that I don't know how to set the value which I want to copy. I know that to get the name of the attribute I can use `field.getName()`, but how can I do the set of that attribute on the new object?

Example:

```java
Test t1 = new Test();
t1.name = "Maria";
t1.age = 30;
t1.street = "somewhere";

Test t2 = new Test();
t2.name = "Maria";
t2.age = ;
t2.street = "here and here";

Test resultIwant = new Test();
t2.name = "Maria";
t2.age = 30;
t2.street = "here and here";
```

Code:

```java
Test resultIwant = new Test(t2);

for(Field field : t1.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Object value1= field.get(t1);
    Object value2= field.get(t2);

    if ((value2 == null && value1 == null) || (value2 == value1))
        continue;
    else {
        if(value2 != null && value1 == null)
            continue;
        else if(value2 == null && value1 != null) {
            resultIwant.set???? = value1; <----------- this is my problem
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65367995/copy-changed-fields-into-an-object-in-java#comment115566202_65367995. It's not exactly the same but same object comparison and copy

Comment: Why should one unpack the Reflection canon for comparing  plain objects!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java Reflection API not only allows you to read but also to set a field value.

In your code you can try the following:

```java
Test resultIwant = new Test(t2);

for(Field field : t1.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object value1= field.get(t1);
        Object value2= field.get(t2);
        
        if ((value2 == null && value1 == null) || (value2 == value1)) 
            continue;
        else {
            if(value2 != null && value1 == null)
                continue;
            else if(value2 == null && value1 != null) {
               String fieldName = field.getName();
               Field fieldOnResultIwant = 
                 resultIwant.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
               fieldOnResultIwant.setAccessible(true);
               // Honestly, I do not remember... Perhaps also will work:
               // field.set(resultIwant, value1);
               fieldOnResultIwant.set(resultIwant, value1);
            }
        }
        
    }
```

I posted a more complete, but related, answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65367995/copy-changed-fields-into-an-object-in-java#comment115566202_65367995).

Comment: Thank you, I will test both solutions.

Comment: You are welcome @porthfind, I hope it helps.